# XCode #include bug - not found in header file but in cxx

Tags: boost, cmake

I created a XCode project with CMake including the Boost 1.55 library and I got into a problem I can't solve by myself.

The include

```
#include "boost/filesystem.hpp"
```

just works in EIATHelper.cxx, but not in header EIATHelper.h. In the header it says "file not found" and consequently the build fails. But still the include seems to work, because Xcode doesn't bitch about the used objects defined in "the missing" filesystem.hpp.

Important! When I put the include and all my code into the .cxx files everything works (build/execute).

I added a screenshot who may helps to understand the problem better. (of course I didn't use the double #include):

[image: xcode error message]

The project is completely created with CMake.

CMakeLists.txt from subfolder header:

```
project(${PROJECT_NAME})

add_library(helper
${PROJECT_NAME}Helper.h
${PROJECT_NAME}Helper.cxx
)

set(BOOST_ROOT /Users/name/Libs/Boost/bin)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED OFF)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)
set(Boost_DEBUG ON)

set(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR /Users/name/Libs/Boost/bin/include)
set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR /Users/name/Libs/Boost/bin/lib)


find_package(Boost COMPONENTS
  system
  filesystem
  log
  log_setup
)

include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

if(NOT Boost_FOUND)
  message("Boost was NOT found")
endif()


target_link_libraries(helper ${BOOST_LIBRARIES})
```

Edit: I created a Eclipse CDT4 Project with CMake, same problem here. Header filsystem.hpp not found in the EIATHelper.h. So I guess something has to be wrong with my project settings, regardless of the IDE.

Comment: What is "/Users/name/Libs/Boost/bin/include"? Are you sure the Boost headers are there?

Comment: Yeah, I am sure. Like I said, the in #include and all code with boost is working as long as I put the code inside the EIATHelper.cxx file! After I moved the include and the prototypes of my methods to the EIATHelpber.h, it said, "boost/filesystem.hpp" is not found but still he finds the defined types inside filesystem.hpp... so maybe its just an issue with xcode?

Comment: Note that the compiler does not compile header files directly. They are compiled indirectly through the source files that pull them in via `#include`. Hence, if you see a compile error in a header file, you first need to find out which source file generated the error. Which `.cxx` files do include the `EIATHelper.h` in your project? You need to make sure that _all_ of them have the Boost directories in their include path.

Comment: EIATHelper.cxx #includes EIATHelper.h -------  EIATHelper.h #includes "boost/filesystem.hpp" -------

Comment: Just a guess, is BOOST_INCLUDEDIR set correctly? The "bin" in the path seems strange.

Comment: The BOOST_INCLUDEDIR is set correctly, the /bin is just the build directory of boost. I just can say it again, everything is working fine in my .cxx file, just when I use the include in my header it says file not found. Same for unix makefile and Eclipse CDT4 Project. I checked the project settings and the makefiles, I can't find any reason for that behavior.

Comment: Can you compile your project? Are there any compiler/linker errors?

Answer (score 1):

> just works in EIATHelper.cxx, but not in header EIATHelper.h

No, it's not. `EIATHelper.cxx` includes `EIATHelper.h`, so "header not found" error appears
first in `EIATHelper.h` and is kind of a fatal error - compilation stops without processing `EIATHelper.cxx` (hence without reporting any errors in `EIATHelper.cxx`).

I'm pretty sure that error is in finding boost libraries. Some notes:

- `BOOST_INCLUDEDIR` and `BOOST_LIBRARYDIR` is a hints. If you set `BOOST_ROOT` and libraries is in a standard paths (lib and include) you don't need them.
- Boost is mandatory for `EIATHelper.{h,cxx}` it's better to use `REQUIRED` suboption
  (you don't need to check `Boost_FOUND`):

> find_package(Boost REQUIRED system filesystem log log_setup)
>
> CMake variables is case-sensitive, use `Boost_LIBRARIES` instead of `BOOST_LIBRARIES`
>
> Do not hardcode `BOOST_ROOT` variable, it's not user friendly. At least do something like that:
>
> ```
> if(NOT BOOST_ROOT)
>   set(BOOST_ROOT /some/default/path/to/boost)
> endif()
> ```